# "Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component" in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-navigation

1. I've already added `<Text></Text>` tag after `return(`, after that the following error resurfaced adjacent tags must be enclosed <></>>
2. Error message: `Text strings must be rendered within a <Text> component`. Please request if you need the entire code.
3. The symbol `&` represents the error it located at `container1`:

   [image]

```js
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import BoxContainer from './components/BoxContainer'

export default class App extends Component {
  //Binding the function with class
 
  buttonClickListener = () => {
    alert("Clicked On Button !!!");
  };

  render() {
    
    return (
<>
     <Text style={styles.headerText}> </Text>
     <View style={styles.page}>
        <BoxContainer style={styles.container3}>
          <View style={[{ width: 50, height : 60, backgroundColor: "orange" }]}>
        
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="BUTTON1"
            color="#00B0FF"
            />
         </View></BoxContainer> 
        
        <BoxContainer style={styles.container1}>
           <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}> 

           <View style={[{ width: "7%", height :200,backgroundColor: "green" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="BUTTON1"
            color="#00B0FF"
            />
          </View>
           <View style={[{ width: "92%", height :300, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
          />
        </MapView> <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="BUTTON1"
            color="#00B0FF"
            />
         </View> </View></View></BoxContainer>
          
    <BoxContainer style={styles.container2}>
           <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
        <View style={[{ width: 400, height :100, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="Button One"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={[{ width: 400,height :90, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="Button Two"
            color="#EC407A"
          />
        </View>

        <View style={[{ width: 400,height :80, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="Button Three"
            color="#1DE9B6"
          />
        </View></View></BoxContainer></View>
</>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  page:{flex:1 ,alignItems: "left"},
 
  container1: {& 
    flex: 7,
    
 map: {position:'absolute'},
    flexDirection: 'row',
    justifyContent: "left",
    alignItems: "left",
    
   
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
   
  },
  container2: {
    flex: 7,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    justifyContent: "left",
    alignItems: "left",
    backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
  },
   
  headerText: {
    fontSize: 10,
    textAlign: "center",
    
    fontWeight: "bold"
  },
  
});
```

Comment: `please request if you need the entire code.` not the entire code, but we do need to see the jsx where this is happening. The style sheet is not causing this error.

Comment: the error is occuring at container1: {~here

Comment: There is no reason that that line of code would cause that error.

Comment: should i upload the whole code-'There is no reason that that line of code would cause that error'

Comment: Just the code that's causing this problem. I don't know why you think that line is at fault, but it can't be. As the error message says, the issue is that you're rendering a string that's not inside a `<Text>` component. How bout showing us where your component is returning JSX

Comment: i've uploaded the whole code so please can you reupload with the rectified code as i didnt quite comprehended your statement:"How bout showing us where your component is returning JSX".

Answer (score 1):

In React Native, a string must be wrapped inside `<Text> string</Text>` component. As it needs to be mapped into native component accordingly which doesn't provide flexibility like HTML.

In React, string without `<div>` or any other component is possible. Since, HTML doesn't give errors on syntax mistake or these type of error.

Comment: it is what i think a runtime  error it dosent appear before i reach the particular screen with the code,i've uploaded the error message displayed in the emulator https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZDgD.png

Answer (score 0):

The code you shared has multiple syntax errors, which makes it hard for me to be sure whether i'm looking at the real issue or not. For example, you close a MapView with `</MapView>`, but there's no MapView anywhere before that.

As best i can tell, the error is caused by this:

```
</View> </View>
```

Since you have a space in the middle of a line of JSX, it's trying to render that space. But in react native, text is only allowed inside a `<Text>` component.

To avoid these issues in the future, I'd recommend you use a tool such as Prettier or Eslint to format your code. By doing that, this would be split onto two lines, and in so doing any white space is irrelevant, because whitespace at the start and end of lines is ignored. The only way to get this error when formatting your code on two lines would be to do something like the following, which would make the error much more easy to spot:

```
  </View>{" "}
</View>
```

Comment: so previously i had the error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? so i moved added <></> then the adjoining elements then that error disappaered and  this error appearedsorry but i'd

Comment: so previously i had the error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>? so i moved added <></> then the adjoining elements then that error disappaered and  this error appearedsorry but i'd omit some elements like map because that did contain some imformation about my location  i did convert the var mapstyle into view mapstyle because  the  i wanted map to enclosed within cotainer and not the whole screen so  if you could rectify the error or just say about it  would  be terrific!

Answer (score 0):

Check that all your components you used are closed
and You have not declared MapView which will certainly
give an error.

And remove & from container 1.

Answer (score 0):

You declared some extra tags of View and also you add MapView Closing tag but you are not adding starting tag. That's why you are facing this error. I remove that tag and also align you code.

Here is the code

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Platform, StyleSheet, Text, View, Button } from "react-native";
import BoxContainer from './components/BoxContainer'

export default class App extends Component {
  //Binding the function with class

  buttonClickListener = () => {
alert("Clicked On Button !!!");
};

render() {

return (
  <>
  <Text style={styles.headerText}> </Text>
  <View style={styles.page}>
    <BoxContainer style={styles.container3}>
      <View style={[{ width: 50, height : 60, backgroundColor: "orange" }]}>
        <Button
          onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
          title="BUTTON1"
          color="#00B0FF"
        />
      </View>
    </BoxContainer>
    <BoxContainer style={styles.container1}>
      <View style={{flexDirection:'row'}}>
        <View style={[{ width: "7%", height :200,backgroundColor: "green" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="BUTTON1"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>
        <View style={[{ width: "92%", height :300, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
          <Button
            onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
            title="BUTTON1"
            color="#00B0FF"
          />
        </View>
      </View>
  </BoxContainer>

<BoxContainer style={styles.container2}>
  <View style={{flexDirection:'column'}}>
    <View style={[{ width: 400, height :100, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "blue" }]}>
      <Button
        onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
        title="Button One"
        color="#00B0FF"
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[{ width: 400,height :90, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "black" }]}>
      <Button
        onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
        title="Button Two"
        color="#EC407A"
      />
    </View>

    <View style={[{ width: 400,height :80, margin: 1, backgroundColor: "red" }]}>
      <Button
        onPress={this.buttonClickListener}
        title="Button Three"
        color="#1DE9B6"
      />
    </View>
  </View>
</BoxContainer>
  </View>
</>
);
}
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
page:{flex:1 ,alignItems: "left"},

container1: {
 flex: 7,
 map: {position:'absolute'},
 flexDirection: 'row',
 justifyContent: "left",
 alignItems: "left",
 backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
},
container2: {
 flex: 7,
 flexDirection: 'column',
 justifyContent: "left",
 alignItems: "left",
 backgroundColor: "#F5FCFF"
},

headerText: {
 fontSize: 10,
 textAlign: "center",
 fontWeight: "bold"
},

});
```